# What data types for GCDAsyncUDPSocket getHost in swift

Tags: ios, swift, gcdasyncsocket

I'm confused.  Here is my code:

```
public func udpSocket(sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket!, didReceiveData data: NSData!, fromAddress address: NSData!, withFilterContext filterContext: AnyObject!) {
   var send_port : UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt16>
   var hostPtr : AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>

   // This appears to be a class level function - not an individual function attached to the sock variable
   GCDAsyncUdpSocket.getHost(&hostPtr, port: &send_port, fromAddress: address)       
}
```

Here is my error:

[image]

**Cannot invoke 'getHost' with an argument list of type '(inout AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer, port: inout UnsafeMutablePointer, fromAddress: NSData!)'**

And here is the "prototype"

```
class func getHost(hostPtr: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>, port portPtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt16>, fromAddress address: NSData!) -> Bool
class func getHost(hostPtr: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>, port portPtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt16>, family afPtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>, fromAddress address: NSData!) -> Bool
```

To me that looks like you pass in:

`AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>`

and a

`UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt16>` which I thought I did.

Any ideas where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the variables as

```
var send_port : UInt16 = 0
var hostPtr : NSString? = nil
```

With `&` the variables are passed as an inout-argument to the function
taking the corresponding `UnsafeMutablePointer` parameters.